# How to treat arrays in legacy VB6 code when migrating to .NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a task migrating old VB6 code to a .NET project. Everything went smoothly converting the old code to the modern VB-dialect, until I hit the array-indexing problem. The old VB code is written assuming that all arrays start at index 1, while arrays in .NET start at 0.

How should I handle this?

1. Rewrite all VB-code so that positions assume a zero-based index?
   (lots of changes)
2. Padd the lower bound of the array with a zero (0)?
3. Other solution?

Comment: You can set the base number to 1 using the `Option Base` declaration:  [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-base-statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-base-statement)

Comment: @DBro: Does that work for VB.NET?

Comment: @Midas No, it does not.

Comment: Oh, that declaration is no longer valid for VB.NET.  I didn't know... sorry for the false info.  In that case, the correct way to approach this is to fix the code to use 0-based indexes.  You have a chance of introducing bugs, but technically, leaving the code as-is exposes you to potential bugs too.  Especially as you move forward with maintaining the code.

Comment: To tell you the truth, I never saw VB6 code that assumes any array boundaries as correct. There is `lbound` and `ubound`, these should be used. I would rewrite the old code to use that everywhere, then it would seamlessly port.

Comment: @GSerg: Considering it is full of complex equations that is going to be a hell :| But what can one do... I will have to taste the sour taste of migrating VB.

Comment: If you have multidimensional arrays, .NET can make them with arbitrary lower bound, even though this isn't directly exposed in the language (look for documentation on System.Array).  You can even do this for single-dimensional arrays, but it will have compatibility issues as .NET customarily compiles single-dimensional arrays to a different type which does not support a non-zero lower bound.

Comment: I'd recommend to eventually implement #1.  I've ranted before about the massive design mistake in .NET of forcing a 0 lower bound, but nearly 20 years in, they're not going to change it.  Anything else will be fighting the language and runtime and surprising users.  (Aside from this big negative, I think you'll find that in most other respects, .NET VB is a massive step forward from VB6.)

Comment: (A) AFAICR the third-party automatic conversion tools can solve this for you. Could be worth a try if you have a big codebase, and a budget to buy them. (B) I'm sure I've also seen code online that emulates 1-based arrays in .Net - but I can't find it now on Google. Basically a simple class with a `Dim` and `Redim` method and default `Item` property, `Lbound` and `Ubound`. You only have to change your array declarations, other code is unchanged including those long equations you mentioned.

Comment: PS plus one, good question, I don't understand why someone has voted to close.

Comment: Ho hum. I see this question is now "on hold". I have voted to reopen it. IMHO this is a perfectly good question.  For whatever it's worth, I am the top user on StackOverflow in the VB6 and VB6-Migration tags (modest cough). @whoever voted to close the question: please leave a comment explaining why this

Comment: Well, I voted to close as primarily opinion based. Yeah, the options are to try to make 1-based in VB.NET or to try to rework the code to be 0-based. I don't think there's much that would really be a good objective answer here, it'd just be listing the tradeoffs. I think this kind of "whiteboarding" talk-out-some-possibilities question might fit better at [softwareengineering.se] than here.

Comment: Although all arrays in VB.NET have a lower bound of zero, allocating an array of n elements results in n+1 (0 to n) elements. If the old code assumes 1 to n indexing, it should still work in VB.NET.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to choose option 1 and take the time to convert the code into something that feels proper .NET.

Option 2 also needs a lot of work (definitely more than obvious at first glance):

@GSerg: If you try

```
Dim myArray As Int32()
ReDim myArray(10) 'creates an array with 11 elements (0..10), could be handy
For i As Int32 = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray) 'LBound is 0, UBound is 10
    Console.Out.WriteLine(i)
Next
```

you get the wrong result and need to adjust your logic as 11 elements are looped.

Same if you create the array like this:

```
Dim myArray(10) As Int32
```

You would have to replace the `LBound` through `1`:

```
Dim myArray As Int32()
ReDim myArray(10) 'creates an array with 11 elements (0..10), could be handy
For i As Int32 = 1 To UBound(myArray) 'LBound is 0, UBound is 10
    Console.Out.WriteLine(i)
Next
```

But as you anyway have to adjust each array, better go for option 1...